# Default.png shows in simulator but not on real device iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

i have added a splash screen to my application by adding Default.png.
the splash screen works fine in the simulator but not showing on real device

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check the case of the file name.

Default.png, default.png, Default.PNG and DEFAULT.png are all different files on the device, but not in the simulator.

Comment: what is the correct case of the file name for device and simulator?

Comment: Device.png with a capital 'D' but no other capitals.

Comment: I think @David Maymudes means Default.png

Comment: Just for the comment: I had some problems adding this myself. Cleaning targets / deleting app from phone before build helps :)

Comment: Awesome. Saved me hours of frustration. Thank you! `:)`

Comment: doesn't work. the image name for me is correct, but on iphone5, i still dont see Default.png being shown.

Answer (score 16):

The file name must be Default.png (with a capital D). Also, do a clean/rebuild of the entire project to ensure the most recent version of the file is being included in the project.

Answer (score 5):

Make a "Default.png" file (with a capital "D"). Then clean all targets and build again.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this issue hapens, when .png file was renamed from .jpg file. 
So, for example, you had image.jpg, you've renamed in to image.png, and using this image.png. It'll be correctly displayed in simulator, and won't work on device

Comment: It was my case, I had to re save the file into png. I wonder if people renaming jpg to png really think they convert the file...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the name of the file begins with a capital "D", then clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Select your Default.png in the groups and files window and make sure in the file listing above the editor window that the checkbox on the far right is checked.  Without this the file will not be copied to the application bundle after compilation is finished.